# Firebase is not defined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Не могу разобраться с настройками импорта/экспорта firebase: у меня выдает ошибку, что 'Firebase' is not defined.

P.S. Сейчас пишет в консоли следующая ошибка: export 'db' (imported as 'db') was not found in './Firebase' (possible exports: default)

Файл App.js:
Скриншот App.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import { db } from './Firebase'; // здесь пишет, что элемент db не экспортирован

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // здесь конфигурация
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Файл Firebase.js:
Скриншот Firebase.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import React from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //      
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default Firebase; // здесь подсказывает, что Firebase is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не определена переменная `Firebase`, поэтому такая ошибка.

Скорее всего вы хотите вернуть `app`, то есть:

```
export default app;
```

Comment: Вроде написала как здесь: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=sr, но консоль выдает ошибку: export 'db' (imported as 'db') was not found in './Firebase' (possible exports: default)

Comment: у вас export default это дефолтовый импорт, а вы импортируете именованный

Comment: вам нужно сделать import app from ..., а не import {app} from ...